# Argparse: unrecognized argument

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to pass some dates via `argparse` to my script, but somehow it always yields the following error:

```
error: unrecognized arguments: -startdate -enddate -timeofday
```

My code is the following:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This program downloads webcam images')
parser.add_argument('‐startdate', type=str, help='startdate given as:dd.mm.YYYY')
parser.add_argument('‐enddate', type=str, help='enddate given as:dd.mm.YYYY')
parser.add_argument('‐timeofday', type=str, help='time of day as:"HH:MM"')
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.startdate
print args.enddate
```

I already tried to use hyphens instead of dots as separators, as well as "real" strings instead of the numbers. Nothing helped. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I think long arguments need two dashes - single-dash is for single-character arguments.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: nope, a single dash is just fine. Provided it is an actual ASCII dash..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the wrong character:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This program downloads webcam images')
>>> parser.add_argument('‐startdate', type=str, help='startdate given as:dd.mm.YYYY')
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='\xe2\x80\x90startdate', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=<type 'str'>, choices=None, help='startdate given as:dd.mm.YYYY', metavar=None)
```

Note the `dest` value there! That's UTF-8 for [U+2010 HYPHEN](http://codepoints.net/U+2010); use an [ASCII `-` minus character](http://codepoints.net/U+002d) instead. Because the string doesn't start with `parser.prefix_chars`, it isn't even recognised as an optional argument, but rather as positional. As a result, `option_strings` is also empty. The help output tells you this too:

```
>>> parser.print_help()
usage: [-h] ‐startdate

This program downloads webcam images

positional arguments:
  ‐startdate  startdate given as:dd.mm.YYYY

optional arguments:
  -h, --help    show this help message and exit
```

It is a positional (required) argument here.

Generally speaking, make sure you are not using a word processor to write code; most likely your simple ASCII `-` dash was replaced by your editor to a *fancy* `‐` HYPHEN character (note how it is rendered shorter). Such editors will also replace quotes and other punctuation with more styled versions.

If I use a regular ASCII minus character things work just fine:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This program downloads webcam images')
>>> parser.add_argument('-startdate', type=str, help='startdate given as:dd.mm.YYYY')
_StoreAction(option_strings=['-startdate'], dest='startdate', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=<type 'str'>, choices=None, help='startdate given as:dd.mm.YYYY', metavar=None)
>>> parser.print_help()
usage: [-h] [-startdate STARTDATE]

This program downloads webcam images

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -startdate STARTDATE  startdate given as:dd.mm.YYYY
```

Comment: Also, adding source encoding headers like `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to source files that are *supposed* to only contain ASCII should be avoided, because they mask exactly this type of mistake.

Comment: True, but this is obviously not the case here - the OP most likely encountered a `SyntaxError` because of non-ASCII characters in his source, and "fixed" it by adding an encoding declaration. Otherwise he couldn't even have gotten an `unrecognized arguments` error.

Comment: @LukasGraf: Right; I forgot this applies to byte strings too. I so rarely use non-ASCII in source files I don't think about the systax error anymore.